# Django rest framework endpoint gives (403 forbidden)

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a `DELETE` request using Axios on my API built with Django rest framework but I keep on getting '403 (forbidden)'
here is my code...

```js
export const deleteLead = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/leads/${id}/`)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_LEAD,
        payload:  id,
      });
    })
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: did you try to make a request with any rest client like insomnia or postman as a sanity check?

Comment: yeah i did with postman and it works fine but when i try the delete request in react using axios i get 403 forbidden

Comment: maybe this happen because of a missing csrf token in your axios request?